# Generate Dockerfile dynamically via maven archetype

Tags: docker, maven, dockerfile, maven-archetype

Let's assume we have multiple application/microservices - all written in java with Spring-boot - which for most cases use the same template for their dockerfies.
All these microservies can be initialized with `maven archetype`.

I'm trying to understand what's the best way - architecture wise - to reduce the maintenance cost for individual developers in terms of maintaining individual dockerfiles.

Ideally **I think** all micorservices' dockerfiles should be generated automatically/dynamically via command line - unless customization is needed.

maven archetype generates the whole project for you afaik from scratch, but is there a way to generate a specific file - `dockerfile` in this case?

let's assume this is the archetype dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine

ENV COMPONENT ${appname}

ENTRYPOINT [/${COMPONENT}/start.sh]
```

I'm looking for something like

```
mvn archetype:generate <artifact/other flags> -file:src/main/dockerfile
```

which would **only** generate the specified `file` : `dockerfile` in target, and can be reused

This reduces the maintenance cost  to almost only the main archetype (e.g. add a common ENV var to all dockerfiles, upgrade java version, etc - with proper versioning)

Any suggestion/alternatives how to handle the case ?

Comment: Are you using archetype for generating the main project as well? You can generate the Dockerfile along with it.